# How to specify encoding format while reading CSV?

Tags: csv, go, utf-8

I am writing a package to read CSV files in Go, and I need to open CSV files which may be coded in different formats (such as UTF8, Latin1 or others). Is there a way to specify the encoding format of the CSV file to read?

Answer (score 11):

> [Package csv](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/)
>
> ```
> import "encoding/csv"
> ```
>
> [func NewReader](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#NewReader)
>
> ```
> func NewReader(r io.Reader) *Reader
> ```
>
> NewReader returns a new Reader that reads from r.

---

Provide an `io.Reader` to `csv.NewReader` that maps the CSV file character set to Unicode UTF-8.

For example,

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

file, err := os.Open(filename)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer file.Close()
rdr := csv.NewReader(charmap.ISO8859_15.NewDecoder().Reader(file))
```

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to determine the type of encoding before reading the file ? What I want to do is the following: make a loop to read csv files which may have several types of encoding: utf-8, latin-1 or others. Is there a way to detec the type of the CSSV file upfront ?